# Is it possible to delete data from all tables within Sqlite Database simultaneously

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

Actually, We need to delete and insert data in all tables when i am going to launch the app. So, please tell me the best solution

Comment: if you can explain little more detail about what you are trying, shall prose the best solution.. are you always looking for a fixed set of data populated when app lauches? do you have to also maintain additional dynamic data that got created later on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes @Dai explanation is correct.

If you going to delete table rows one by one for each table than it is memory consuming too.

It takes bit of time to remove all table's rows. Also you need to query separately for each table and need to check that *constraint are not conflict with other table*.

Suppose, Table A is reference to Table B than you must have to remove Table B records before going to remove Table A records.

There are many things needs to check before going to removing each tables records.

As @Dai said that if dropping table is no issue with your current implementation.

I would suggest you one step ahead of this. Why don't you remove your database any copy it from bundle.

As per my knowledge we are creating database and place it in a application bundle. So if the previous state of database is not required than you just remove database and copy new from application bundle.

**This would be very fast to perform on application launch.**

Answer (score 1):

It's actually more efficient to drop the table and recreate them - and if you're going to do that then you might as well delete the database file and recreate it (and thus not subject yourself to unnecessary fragmentation or database expansion).